# How can I distort randomly generated lines along a pattern so that they flow around the bright areas of the pattern like a gravitational lens?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

Day 4 of my personal Shader Nodes learning path.

Please forgive me if the title is worded a bit stupid. I still hope to add value to this platform and ask an interesting question.

> Basically, this question is based on the following previously created questions:
>
> - [How to create a seamless diagonal wavy pattern with opposing waves?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293774/)
> - [How can I match the noise to a wavy pattern?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293820/)
>
> ...but with a completely different goal.

Let's say I have the following pattern, which I created using the question/answer posed earlier:

[image]

And in addition to that, I have created diagonal lines using a Noise Texture:

[image]

And now I would like to distort the lines so that they curve around the brighter areas. So to speak, to avoid this or to be distorted/pushed away by it, so something like this, only I imagine it to be much more intensive:

[image]

However, if I increase the amplitude of the sine waves on the basis of my current setup, discontinuities arise in the lines, since it is a matter of two functions working separately from each other that are pieced together.

[image]

As a reminder, this approach, no doubt bungled by me, is based on two such patterns, one of which is processed inverted:

[image]

It is clear to me that the previous approach is not correct for this, and that a completely different mechanism is needed here.

Only which one?

In this example, I am not necessarily concerned with representing exactly as I use it in my examples, but primarily with the question of how diagonally running lines can be bent in a wave-like manner around certain points. It should just look cool, because if it looks cool, it's right!

Please help a *Blender novice** in exploring this universe. Thanks!

<sub>* In the [shader-nodes](/questions/tagged/shader-nodes) section</sub>

Here is the node tree and blend file I use to create the examples shown above:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After receiving some great guidance from *@RobinBetts* and *@MarkusvonBroady* on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293884/), I was able to solve this task to my satisfaction.

And the answer seems to be simpler than I originally thought.

Stupidly, my current knowledge of [shader-nodes](/questions/tagged/shader-nodes) is not yet sufficient to describe it all with the quality you've come to expect from me on [geometry-nodes](/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes), but I'll post the answer in a nutshell:

[image]

Essentially, what I'm doing here is simply adding the value that results from multiplying sine and cosine to the x-axis of the vector for the noise texture.

This pattern looks like this:

[image]

And the end result is distorted diagonal curves:

[image]

Here is the blend file for it:

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+)*</sub>

Comment: .. can't really improve on this answer, but [this sort of approach](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NnjsJzyr/) might be of interest. I find it's often useful to think of a 2D texture as a height-map into, or a slice out of, a 3D texture. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243958/35559) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559), for example. Thinking of your tone as a 'height' map, you can even explore using its gradient as a parameter, by putting it through _Vector > Bump_